# How to import local json file data to my JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I have data inside employees.json how can I get this data and assign it to the variable inside main.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `require` that file.

```
const data = require("./data.json");
```

Here's a working example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-rgb-75z4o/ in `React`. Lmk if you have any doubts.

Comment: it says require is not defined

Comment: What if you don't use React?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to import json data in main js file. So your main.js file looks like:

```
const employees = require('./employees.json');
```

Now you can use employees variable that contains json data.

Comment: it says require is not defined

Comment: You can use **import * as employees from './emplyees.json';**

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Babel**, you can use this:

```
import * as data from './employees.json';
const employees = data;
```

You can use another method using js file.

**employees.js**

```
export default
{
  // your json here...
}
```

And then:

```
import data from '../employees.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help,Using the Fetch API:

```
fetch("employees.json")
     .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => data = (json));
```